# ActiveMq and Oracle AQ bridge error

Tags: activemq-classic, oracle-aq

I am trying to extract messages from AQ into topic in ActiveMq. I followed this instructions: http://activemq.apache.org/jms-bridge-with-oracle-aq.html . But when I started ActiveMQ I got this error:

```
2015-09-02 12:33:18,269 | WARN  | Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'event_queue' - trying to recover. Cause: JMS-137:  Payload factory must be specified for destinations with ADT payloads | org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer | Camel (camel) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[event_queue]
```

What is the reason for this error and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found solution. So, at first AQ supports messages of the following types:

- • RAW Queues • Oracle Object (ADT) Type Queues • Java Message Service
  (JMS) Type Queues/Topics

---

The reason for this error(JMS 137) is the ADT payload is not valid for using with ActiveMq. And if you are planning to make a bridge between ActiveMq and Oracle AQ you should use JMS Types. 
The other thing is that I could not find required aqjms.jar, I replaced it with aqapi.jar from jlib directory of my Oracle Client. 
Also beans tag attributes should be:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
```